# allow_url_fopen local variable

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, recaptcha

I added recaptcha in phpMyAdmin by adding the two variables

> $cfg['CaptchaLoginPublicKey'] = 'Site key';
>
> $cfg['CaptchaLoginPrivateKey'] = 'Secret key';

but I got errors below.

```
Warning in ./libraries/plugins/auth/recaptcha/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Post.php#68
 file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

Backtrace

./libraries/plugins/auth/recaptcha/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Post.php#68: file_get_contents(
string 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
boolean false,
resource,
)
./libraries/plugins/auth/recaptcha/ReCaptcha/ReCaptcha.php#94: ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\Post->submit(object)
./libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.class.php#366: ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha->verify(
string '03AHJ_VuvVnV4jlI2mNDNogB6eajU4jE--F7ve8zMdP0Xf636gaBeNE_dK9-',
string '10.0.5.1',
)
./libraries/common.inc.php#896: AuthenticationCookie->authCheck()
./index.php#12: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)

Warning in ./libraries/plugins/auth/recaptcha/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Post.php#68
file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found

Backtrace

./libraries/plugins/auth/recaptcha/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Post.php#68: file_get_contents(
string 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
boolean false,
resource,
)
./libraries/plugins/auth/recaptcha/ReCaptcha/ReCaptcha.php#94: ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\Post->submit(object)
./libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.class.php#366: ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha->verify(
string '03AHJ_VuvVnV4jlI2mNDNogB6eajU4jE--F7ve',
string '10.0.5.1',
)
./libraries/common.inc.php#896: AuthenticationCookie->authCheck()
./index.php#12: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
```

so I want to turn on the allow_url_fopen for phpMyAdmin.  I changed /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini to

> allow_url_fopen = On
>
> allow_url_include = On

The root phpinfo shows me the correct settings.

```
Directive           Local Value    Master Value
allow_url_fopen     On             On
allow_url_include   On             On
```

However, in the phpMyAdmin folder.

```
Directive           Local Value    Master Value
allow_url_fopen     Off            On
allow_url_include   On             On
```

so I tried the PHP to test in phpMyAdmin folder.

> ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true);
>
> if (ini_get("allow_url_fopen") == true) { echo "allow_url_fopen is ON"; }
>
> else { echo "allow_url_fopen is OFF"; }
>
> print ini_get("allow_url_fopen");
>
> print ini_get("allow_url_include");
>
> exit;

```
allow_url_fopen is OFF01
```

I also tried to add .htaccess in phpMyAdmin folder.

> php_value allow_url_fopen On

Why the local value cannot be changed in phpMyAdmin folder?

My server is Debian8.2, PHP5.6.17, phpMyAdmin4.5, MySQL5.7 and it's behind a firewall.

I know it's dangerous to set the global allow_url_fopen to On.  How can I just set it available to the phpMyAdmin folder only?

Comment: You can not change this flag on-the-fly due to security issue. You need to check you php.ini configuration (both php.ini file, and php flags in webserver configuration)

Comment: So you mean to change the config in /etc/php5/apache2/php5.ini ? I changed and root folder works but phpmyadmin folder does not work.

Comment: How about the vhost file? Does it have any change on PHP flags?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tuan.  Yes, you are right.   I modified the vhost and it works now.

> vim /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
>
> php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen On
>
> php_admin_flag allow_url_include On